# Type conversion issue leading to wrong result in multitype expression

Tags: c, casting, calculation

I'm doing a calculation involving multiple types. However, it gives me the wrong result.

How can i fix this?

Here is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    long int numberOfOccurence;
    long int occurencesPerSub = 7;
    long int n = 736778906400;
    int c = 100;

    numberOfOccurence = ((float)occurencesPerSub / c)*n;
    printf("%ld", numberOfOccurence);

    return 0;
}
```

As a result `numberOfOccurence` is 51574525952 but it is supposed to be 51574523448, instead.

Comment: Use double instead of float. For big numbers float does not have a representation for each natural number.

Comment: @pqans `double` also doesn't have a representation for all natural numbers. It's just that the limit is higher

Comment: @phuclv No fixed length data type have a representation for all natural numbers ;)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. However, in most such simple cases double is just enough when float fails.

Answer (score 1):

float does not have enough digits of precision to produce the answer you require.

When using conversions, all of the types in the sub-expression have to have enough precision to hold the full result in order for the answer to be accurate.  float only has 6-9 digits of precision.

Your answer is correct within 6-9 significant figures.